# Unenclosed <li> element without <ul> or <ol> creates bullet point outside text area

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, list

If I simply put a bare `<li>...</li>` Element like below in my post, without wrapping it in a `<ol>...</ol>` or `<ul>...</ul>` as usual, it still creates an unordered list item with a bullet point, but the indentation is messed up: Text starts at the left text area border and the bullet point is outside of it.

```
<li>See this example</li>
```

See this example

The same happens also if the enclosing list tags are somehow misspelled or not closed properly.

---

I believe it should look like a regular unordered list, as created by either this HTML or Markdown snippet below:

```
<ul><li>HTML</li></ul>
- Markdown
```

- HTML

- Markdown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eh. Using plain HTML within posts is mostly supported, but not really encouraged - especially not when there are Markdown equivalents. If you choose to use HTML instead anyway, it's on you to make sure it's actually correct.

In other words, ["garbage in, garbage out"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) is the expected behaviour here.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you on preferring Markdown. The issue above came to my attention in a new user's post. I edited it, discovered the described pattern, and replaced it with Markdown. Still, new users quite often tend to try formatting with HTML as they don't know (about) Markdown, and might do it wrong. The outcome in this case just looks really weird.

Comment: @ByteCommander much of this page is made up of lists. These comments are lists. Care will have to be taken when changing the style for these orphan `li`s that it doesn't inadvertently break other things. Probably not worth the effort, when editors have to clean up a lot of formatting anyway. (I recently saw a new user do ```text...`code` commands `code` text...```, so that only `code` was in code formatting and the actual commands weren't. :|) We have to edit those anyway.